# ofstream(mode ios::out) wipes existing file blank when system halt

Tags: c++, boost, iostream, ofstream, boost-propertytree

The usage scenario is industrial (unstable power supply and other buggy programs/hardware). It is required that the program should come back unaffected when power is off (or blue-screen crash). OS is Windows 7 with NTFS.

I use boost::property_tree write json to record parameters to human readable text file.

```
boost::property_tree::write_json("logic.txt", pt);
```

It actually wiped the "logic.txt" sometimes, when system halt.
I read the boost source file and write_json calls ofstream with default ios::out

```
std::basic_ofstream<typename Ptree::key_type::value_type> stream(filename.c_str());
```

The problem should be ofstream wipe the existing file and leaves blank file when system fails.

Is this a known problem with ofstream? What is the most suitable solution to this ?
I can think of a few:

1. Write file to "logic_tmp.txt" first, when finished, delete "logic.txt" and rename the temp file to logic.txt.
2. Using SQLite instead of writing to file directly. (MySQL broke some times, table required to be "repaired" when start up again, SQLite hasn't failed me yet)

any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: "Eat My Data: How Everybody Gets File IO Wrong" see https://www.flamingspork.com/talks/ (vid cached here: http://downloads.sehe.nl/zfs-fuse/File_IO_Safety.ogg)

Comment: @sehe Interesting talk, i assume multiple SQLite (avoid large file and minimize race) with 'force flush' could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is your #1: write to a temporary file then rename.  However, do note that for the rename to be atomic, the temporary file should be on the same filesystem.  Safest would be to simply store it in the same directory.  And of course you can use `mkstemp()` or similar to make sure you have a unique temporary filename.

The above is still not a 100% guarantee on all possible systems, because it depends on your filesystem semantics (you didn't tell us what filesystem you're using).

If you want a more bullet-proof solution, your #2 is a good idea: use SQLite.  It's been tested in a lot of scenarios like you describe.  See https://www.sqlite.org/testing.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. They system runs on Windows 7 with NTFS, can you elaborate on filesystem semantics?

Comment: On NTFS the tempfile solution will be fine.  To elaborate: some filesystems like FAT suck and get screwed up intrinsically on power loss etc.  But you aren't using one of those, so don't worry about it.

Comment: Solution #1 is something I learnt from TurboPascal IDE roundabout 25 years ago but I still use it for our productive software when appropriate. Our testers/customers had/have many complaints but they never complained about a lost project (5 minutes before dead-line). ;-)